# How to output multiple S3 buckets address

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a terraform code which creates multiple buckets but I am not able to figure out how to output addresses of all the buckets that will be created?

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["uniquebucket1", "uniquebucket2"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "newbuckets" {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  bucket        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"

}

output "bucket_name" {
    value = "${aws_s3_bucket.newbuckets.*.bucket}"
}
```

The output doesn't work as I want clean address of the buckets & what I get back is an array of just primary names. Has someone dealt with this?

Thanks but what I get back is this-

```
Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

bucket_name = [
    uniquebucket1,
    uniquebucket2
]
```

Comment: Try this `output "bucket_names" {
    value = ["${aws_s3_bucket.newbuckets.*.bucket}"]
}`

Comment: Thanks Chetan, please see my edit above in original question. This is after implementing the fix you suggested.

Comment: What information do you need from the created buckets? if you want arn of the buckets you can do `"bucket_names" { value = ["${aws_s3_bucket.newbuckets.*.bucket.arn}"] }`

Comment: What do you mean by "clean address of the buckets"? Do you mean the ARN? The website/HTTPS URLs?

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you see the console output above, it is returning in an array and I was hoping that I could deserialize it somehow. I know I can get ARN, bucket_domain_address to output but can I get rid of the array and just have the address returned?

Comment: You are creating buckets do you get back is bucket objects. You need to access properties of these buckets to get the details of them. ARN is one such property.